# How can I create a button in Wordpress that will send me a text message when pressed?

Tags: button, sms

First off I'm a novice to programming.  I'm looking for help to create a button on my Wordpress site that will send me a text message when someone presses it.  I have a Twilio account set up but I don't know that code that is required on my Wordpress page to prompt a button to initiate a text message.

If it helps, here is my button:

[button link="www.healthyteenproject.com" color="green" size="xlarge" type="flat" shape="pill" target="_self" title="notify" gradient_colors="333333" gradient_hover_colors="444444" accent_color="111111" accent_hover_color="222222" bevel_color="111111" border_width="0px" shadow="no" icon="fa-envelope" icon_divider="yes" icon_position="left" modal="" animation_type="none" animation_direction="up" animation_speed="2"]Notify Dr. Zumarraga that you are here for your appointment[/button]

I really appreciate any help people can provide.

Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for the code and just want the button to work on your page, you can look for a plugin that will do this for you.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordio/ is one of the plugin I came across.

It looks pretty easy to install based on the description.

Hope it helps.